# Как заставить аннтотацию SpringMVC @GetMapping не игнорировать css оформление?

Tags: java, css, spring-mvc

Собственно есть код контроллера

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/direction")
public String directionIdPage(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) throws Exception {

    model.addAttribute("directionAll", directionService.findAllDirection());
    model.addAttribute("directionId", directionService.findDirectionById(id).orElseThrow(Exception::new));

    return "directionID";
}
```

При переходе на страницу допустим "5/direction" открывается страница без css оформления.

Но стоит изменить на @GetMapping("/{id}"), как проблема решается и все шаблоны css сразу видны.

В чём проблема не могу понять введите сюда описание изображения

[image: Страница без оформления]

А вот та же страница с оформлением

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все ссылки на оформление представлены как

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/themify-icons/0.1.2/css/themify-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/linearicons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nice-select.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

Comment: @GetMapping(value = "/{id}/direction")

Comment: Вы уверены, что проблема с контроллером? Может у вас ссылки на css относительные, а не абсолютные?

Comment: Все ссылки в формате <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/linearicons.css">

Comment: css/linearicons.css подразумевает, что стиль находит в той же папке что и файл, но еще в дочерней папке css. МОжет вам надо указать /css/linearicons.css со слешкой?

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает. При наведении курсора на путь в Intelli j Idea он чётко показывает где лежит данный css. Но оформление всё равно не применяет

Comment: Значение имеет не то, где в исходном коде лежат файлы, а по каким путям (url-ам) они доступны из веб. Какой полный url вы вводите для страницы?

Comment: localhost:8016/onlearn/{id}/direction (тут оформления не видит когда контроллер @GetMapping(value = "/{id}/direction"). Но если localhost:8016/onlearn/{id} (при @GetMapping(value = "/{id}" то всё окей)